# joint mgf for multinomial distribution

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{k-1}$ have a multinomial distribution. I need to find the mgf of $X_2, \cdots X_{k-1}$. I think it should be 
\begin{align*}
M_{X}(0, t_2, \cdots, t_{k-1})= (p_1+p_{2}e^{t_{2}}+\cdots p_{k}e^{t_k})^{n}.
\end{align*}.

I don't know if this is correct or how simple it should be, I have been getting confused about the multinomial mgf. Any explanation appreciated.

Comment: The general form of the moment-generating function is indeed $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^k p_ie^{t_i}\right)^n. $$ Are you having trouble in deriving this expression?

Comment: I am having trouble, I can't seem to find anything helpful online.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282454/moment-generating-function-of-multinomial-distribution

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful -- I've noticed sometimes people define the mgf as $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_{i}e^{t_{i}}+p_{k}$. Are they equivalent somehow? This is why I was so confused..

Comment: That doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Okay. I've also had to work through a typo in my textbook, which didn't help my confusion. Would my answer to the question in the original post be correct, then?